# Nature of f(x,y) if y is an increasing function of x

Tags: calculus

[This is the link to the question in case the question below is not legible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYKf9.jpg)

Let f:R2→R be a twice-differentiable function with non-zero second partial derivatives. Suppose that for every x∈R, there is a unique value of y, say y∗(x), that solves the problem maxy∈R f(x,y)

Then y∗ is increasing in x if A. f is strictly concave B. f is strictly convex C. ∂2f∂x∂y>0 D. ∂2f∂x∂y<0

My work: since y is increasing in x, the graph would be upward sloping, so the answer should be either convex or cross second derivative greater than 0.

we are given the following information:
1. Non zero second derivative- this means it's not a saddle point
2. For every x, there is a unique value of y- this might not have a max or min ( eg: f(x) = x in the single variable case) 
so the answer should be c

I am not quite sure about my approach. Would be grateful if you could share yours. Thanks!

Any book recommendation where I can find such questions would be helpful. Thanks!